# Creating Excel sheet using vb.net using framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net

I have .net framework 2.0 . and I want to create an Excel sheet from vb.net programming. I have searched in google but didn't get the correct one. It was all for .net framework 3.5 or higher.
Please show me code to generate a simple Excel file using vb.net programming.

Comment: Is upgrading your framework not an option? What is your datasource? What have you tried? Is creating a CSV an option? Please clarify your question...

Answer (score 2):

How's this look?  This code has been around in one of my applications since pre-.NET 2.0 and should work for you.

```
'Grab data from the data grid view and put it on the clipboard
Clipboard.SetDataObject(Me.dgvData.GetClipboardContent())

'Create excel and workbook objects
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

'Now paste in the data that was copied to the clipboard above
oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select()
oBook.Worksheets(1).Paste()
```

You will likely need to include `Interop.Excel.dll` in your project references.

**Edit:** Also, if you have time to read something, this is a pretty awesome write up on the more current version that may help you as well http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/